# Would my recent medical leave show up during the background check by a potential employer?

Tags: background-check, canada

I am just wondering about whether my recent medical leave (I am not currently on a medical leave, but I had been on one from June to the early October of this year) will show up during the background check by a potential employer?

I haven't received any government aid for my medical leave, my current company had offered me a paid medical leave.

During the background check, would my potential employer realize that I had been on medical leave with the current employer recently? I am just worried that this can make my potential employer to not to hire me.

Thank you,

Comment: Where are you? The answer may depend on regional laws.

Comment: I live in Canada.

Comment: Cool - I don't know the situation in Canada but hopefully somebody else here will.

Comment: Even if it comes up... "I am just worried that this can make my potential employer to not to hire me." why would that be happening? Why do you think that medical leave would negatively impact your employability?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul in an ideal world, medical leave wouldn't matter. Even though it's illegal, some companies will not hire employees with a history of major illness -- they believe the potential cost is too high of a risk. That's in part why medical information is so highly protected, to prevent access to information that can support discriminatory intent. It's like protections against pre-existing conditions -- certainly people with a history of a given illness are more likely to develop complications, but that doesn't make it fair or just to deny them insurance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> During the background check, would my potential employer realize that I had been on medical leave with the current employer recently?

I am not a lawyer, but many countries, [including Canada](https://www.priv.gc.ca/en/privacy-topics/privacy-laws-in-canada/the-personal-information-protection-and-electronic-documents-act-pipeda/pipeda_brief/), have laws protecting the privacy of medical information. Medical information cannot be provided in response to an employment verifcation request.

Typically a background check includes employer information, dates of employment, and job title. Only if you left the company, and were subsequently rehired, would a potential employer know that some event happened, but they wouldn't know the reason.  If you were on paid medical leave, you would still be legally employed by the company, so no gap would appear in your employment history.

Even if there were such a gap, it's extremely unlikely that your employer would share the reasons for your departure at all, much less provide medical information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are US-based: Most background checks are related to credit and criminal checks. Recent speeding tickets? Likely. Medical leave... no. It would be of dubious legality due to HIPAA. Either way, most background checks are extremely basic. Even government clearance investigations wouldn't care about medical leave.

That said, if you had a serious medical issue that caused you to take that leave, why would you want to work for a company that's going to have issues with it? What happens if you need to take similar leave again?

Comment: Supporting a current employee means you're protecting a (potentially highly) valueable asset. Hiring otoh is just expensive.

Comment: @Karl this is true in most cases. I started a position less than a month ago, told them I would have to miss considerable time, and they gave me PTO for 2 weeks right off the top. Depends on the situation for them and you, and how they interpret it.

Comment: PTO - *Pacific Theater of Operations* ? ;-)

Comment: @Karl Paid Time Off

Comment: The stock answer to "why would you want to work for a company that does BadThing" is "because sometimes people need employment in order to pay for food/rent/medical bills/etc. and they might not have a better option". Especially this year when many people are in precarious situations.